# WPF Border using plain black rectangle

Tags: wpf, border

How can I get the border in WPF to use a plain black rectangle? It always appears to have thicker bottom and left lines which I guess is a shadow effect even though I have no effects applied. I don't want to use a rectangle as I am using this to apply a border around a grid containing controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `SnapsToDevicePixels="true"`. Like this:

```
<Border Width="200" Height="200" 
        BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" 
        SnapsToDevicePixels="true"></Border>
```

For me, this removed the varying thickness of the borders.